# How to make service to sleep from main activity

Tags: android, android-service

I've a requirement to create a service in android and make the service to sleep for 10 mins from `MainActivity`.

How can I make service to sleep from activity ?

MyService.java

```
    public class MyService extends IntentService {

    public MyService() {
        super("MyService");
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // Extract the receiver passed into the service
        ResultReceiver rec = intent.getParcelableExtra("receiver");
        // Extract additional values from the bundle
        String msg = intent.getStringExtra("msg");
        // To send a message to the Activity, create a pass a Bundle
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("res", msg);
        // Here we call send passing a resultCode and the bundle of extras
        rec.send(Activity.RESULT_OK, bundle);
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button serviceTriggerBtn;
public MyReceiver receiver;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    serviceTriggerBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.serviceTriggerBtn);

    serviceTriggerBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class);
            i.putExtra("msg", "ACTIVITY DATA");
            startService(i);
        }
    });
}

// Setup the callback for when data is received from the service
public void setupServiceReceiver() {
    receiver = new MyReceiver(new Handler());
    // This is where we specify what happens when data is received from the service


    receiver.setReceiver(new MyReceiver.Receiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    String resultValue = resultData.getString("msg");
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, resultValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

I registered the service in manifest file and service is calling correctly. But I'm stuck to make service sleep. Please help me.

Comment: If you know how long to let the service sleep, don't do it. Just finish it and restart after that amount of time. Most likely you wouldn't have a guarantee for it not being finished by the system.

Comment: Why does your `Service` need to sleep for 10 minutes? Please explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: It's a case study for me to complete few courses. But I did it. I've used thread.sleep in side serivce OnHandleIntent method. Thanks for all your support.